# How does textarea format with HTML tags inside, but not show?

Tags: jquery, html

It was hard to word this question but I have some visuals to show you what I mean.

**Text**

[image]

If I get the `.val` of the "text" `<textarea>` it plays nice in my app, it mirrors the wordpress textarea fine.

---

My issue is if I get the `.val()` of the "visual" (tinyMCE) content it displays with `<p>` tags

**My Plugin**

[image]

I understand the wordpress tinyMCE is inside an `iframe` and looking at it with firebug, its not actually a `<textarea>` its just plain HTML using `contentEditable="true"` and I suspect that's my issue.

So if you are not familiar with what I am saying I could just ask how do I get the `.val()` from (changing) plain HTML without displaying the `<p>` tags in my textarea? Do I need to send it to a hidden input?

Any help would be great this is absolutely irritating me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

val returns exactly what is in the textarea. In your first example, it looks like it is showing and retrieving from a rendered (or view mode in a WYSIWTG editor) textarea, so no p tags come with it. In the second. you are looking at code view, so the code will come with it.

You could loop through the code and get rid of any

```
  <p> and </p> tags
```

BUT that's not a good solution as what about the myriads of others tags that might be there.

Instead, can you tell me what you do with the code you grab via val()? One possible solution is simply to output his code, tags and all, into a div or span, and the browser will then use those tags properly (i.e.

will provide paragraph indentation,  changes font and color etc)

```
$("#myTargetDiv").append($("#myTextArea").val());
```

Comment: Yeah actually looking at a sample plugin I noticed that is what they did.. I am going to append the content and if the user wants to edit it they can open a thick box which contains the wp editors to edit the content..